# Pasting anywhere without Robot class

Tags: java, paste

I want to be able to paste my text where the user currently is typing. It should be possible in every program. Not just mine.
I already found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631933/how-would-i-make-a-paste-from-java-using-the-system-clipboard). But I am of course not able to use the [first, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694596/15403976) because I want to be able to paste in other programs.

I also don´t think it´s a good idea using the Robot class as [some other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631952/15403976) suggested. Because random errors could occur.

Is there really no other, not hacky solution doing this?

Comment: What user problem are you trying to solve by pasting text into Notepad, as one example?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Didn´t see it. Pasting text into notepad would be one example, yes.

Comment: My question is why?  How does your function help the user?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I press CTRL + V a custom GUI pops up and you can choose what you want to paste. If you chose one of the options I want to be able to also paste it

Comment: Java is not the language of choice for a GUI like this.  You need a language that connects better with the operating system, either Windows or Unix.  Windows, as an example, has [clipboard managers](https://windowsreport.com/clipboard-managers-windows-10/) already available.